# how to decorate different words with different decorations with textspan in flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to get some words from a string and give those words different colors and decoration. So far I have been able to do this for a single word with the code below and `it works for single word`. I have tried a couple of other ways but none seems to be working with multiple words. How can I achieve this with multiple words.

**Code that works for single word**

```
   List<TextSpan> _getSpans(String text, String matchWord, TextStyle style) {

      final style2 = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,
      );

      List<TextSpan> spans = [];
      int spanBoundary = 0;

      do {

        // look for the next match
        final startIndex = text.indexOf(matchWord, spanBoundary);

        // if no more matches then add the rest of the string without style
        if (startIndex == -1) {
          spans.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(spanBoundary)));
          return spans;
        }

        // add any unstyled text before the next match
        if (startIndex > spanBoundary) {
          spans.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(spanBoundary, startIndex)));
        }

        // style the matched text
        final endIndex = startIndex + matchWord.length;
        final spanText = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        spans.add(TextSpan(text: spanText.replaceAll(RegExp(r"`"), "\n"), style:style,
        //recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
        // do something
        //},
        ));

        // mark the boundary to start the next search from
        spanBoundary = endIndex;

      // continue until there are no more matches
      } while (spanBoundary < text.length);

      return spans;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you could use something like this without using regex:

```
 List<TextSpan> _getSpans(
    String text,
    List<String> matchWords,
    TextStyle style,
  ) {
    var wordsMap = Map.fromIterable(text.split(' '),
        key: (v) => v, value: (v) => TextSpan(text: v));

    for (var matchWord in matchWords) {
      if (wordsMap.containsKey(matchWord)) {
        wordsMap[matchWord] = TextSpan(text: matchWord, style: style);
      }
    }

    var spanList = wordsMap.values.toList();

    //adding missing spaces
    for (var i = 0; i < spanList.length - 1; ++i) {
      spanList[i] =
          TextSpan(text: spanList[i].text + ' ', style: spanList[i].style);
    }

    return spanList;
  }
```

Comment: I would not be knowing what type of text data the user would input, regex would help me get some specific pattern in the text and highlight them